# What's the name of this specific style of craft ball?

Tags: material-identification, kids-crafts

How would you describe this type of craft ball? It is about 3/4" in diameter with small, thin, shiny, glimmery ribbons. It's more compact and dense than most of the fuzzy craft balls I've found online or in most store. I'm desperately trying to find more of these as unfortunately I've lost the only one I had. If you can please help provide a description for this exact type or name of craft ball as to be able to find it online for purchase.

I've included a picture below to hopefully help (sorry for the attached fuzz, but it's the only picture I have).

Thank you for any help you can provide.

[image: Fuzzy craft ball with shiny, glimmery ribbons roughly 3/4" in diameter]

Comment: Is it like a pom pom? I’ve seen tinsel (also sparkle) pom poms that look similar. Though they might not be as dense.

Comment: Is the ball like a dense pom pom, or a solid ball covered with tinsel?  Maybe try "tinsel ball"?

Comment: It's definitely denser than the standard glimmer/tinsel fuzz craft balls. It weighs a bit more and there seems to be more tinsel ribbons that the standard glimmer/tinsel fuzz craft balls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it might have been a cat toy... I originally found it in this online shop: [www.catsnus.com](https://www.catsnus.com/kitty-puff-tinsel-ball-cat-toy/), but they're available in many shops. They even have a picture of a comparison of a regular, soft crafting pompom and their dense cat pompom.

[image]

[image]